# If 4 people have five meal choices how many different ways can they order?

Tags: combinatorics

If 4 people have five meal choices, and multiple people can have the same meal. How many different ways can they order?

Comment: I tried taking 20 possible meals total and partition them into 4 groups by taking 20!/5!*5!*5!*5!, but I think this would use up all 20 meals when really I only want to use 5 of the 20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $(5^4)$ possible ways in which four people may order their meals, assuming everyone orders one meal. (Remember, everyone may order the same meal.)

Person 1: 5 choices 
Person 2: 5 choices 
Person 3: 5 choices 
Person 4: 5 choices

Multiply: $5 \cdot 5\cdot 5\cdot 5 = 5^4 = 625$ possible meal orders for 4 people.

If some can opt to fast (not order anything), so everyone orders at most one meal, then there are $(6^4)$ possible ways four people may order their meals, since now each of the 4 people actually have $6$ choices, one of which is simply not ordering anything offered.

Comment: What if two people were to get the same meal how could I subtract those?

Comment: Would it work like this Person 1: 5 choices, Person 2: 1 choice because they have to be the same as Person 1, Person 3: 5 choices, and Person 4: 5 choices for a total of 5*5*5*1 = 125 ways.